# Asterisk Make Menu Select mysql_odbc option is disabled

Tags: asterisk, cdr

I am trying to compile asterisk.

Version : **13.28.0**

I am want to store my CDR into database, So I want to install mysql_odbc addon while compiling/installing asterisk.
However when I am compiling it I am getting the MYSQL_ODBC disabled (XXX). How do I resolve the dependencies  ? or what should I do so that I can select mysql_odbc. Looks something like this :

[image: Error Image]

What should I install to make this happen ?

I am using OpenSUSE, as operating system

Answer (score 0):

There are no mysql-odbc in asterisk.

If you want install odbc, you should install unixodbc-devel library.